# How to return multiple data/objects from a dependency function in FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, fastapi, starlette, depends

I am using FastAPI framework and writing some data into PostgreSQL database.  The issue I am encountering is that I have a function `get_current_user()` that returns user credentials (including email), but I am not sure how to access this data from another function `s3_create_upload_files()`.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to write the email address and the filename that I am going to upload to the same line in the database after the file is successfully uploaded.

**get_current_user()**

```
async def get_current_user(
    request: Request,
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
):
    token = request.cookies.get("Authorization")

    if token is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=302, headers={"Location": '/auth/login'})

    token = token.split("Bearer ")[-1]

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'), algorithms=["HS256"])
        email: str = payload.get("sub")
        if email is None:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=302, headers={"Location": '/auth/login'})
    except jwt.exceptions.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=302, headers={"Location": '/auth/login'})

    user = db.query(User).filter(User.email == email).first()
    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=302, headers={"Location": '/auth/login'})
    
    print(f'Email is {user.email}')

    return user  # Ensure 'user' is a User object
```

**s3_create_upload_files()**

```
async def s3_create_upload_files(
    file: UploadFile = File(...),
    current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user), 
    db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
....CODE HERE,,,,

        # Insert data into the database after successful upload
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        file_data = User(filename=sanitized_filename, email=current_user.email)
        db.add(file_data)
        db.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I have tried a few different ways to receive the data in `s3_create_upload_files()` but all of them cause an error on the HTML side.  `Same error has come about again "{"detail":"'Depends' object has no attribute 'email'"}"`

The error in the backend says
`INFO:     192.168.65.1:62133 - "POST /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: One way would be to return a `list` or `dict` of the various objects you would like returning, or create a custom Python class with those fields, instantiate it in the `get_current_user()` dependency function, and return it. Alternatively, one could store such arbitrary data to the `request.state`, and access them in the endpoint using the `Request` object - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804).

Comment: Thank you Chris, the request.state seems like a nice approach.  I will do some more reading on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using one of the approaches described below.

### Option 1 - Return a `list` or `dict` of data

Return a `list` of data from the dependency function, and define a proper parameter in the endpoint to expect these data in the appropriate form.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    
    
async def get_user_data():
    user = User(name='john', age=33)
    email = 'user@domain.com'
    return [user, email]


@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(data: list = Depends(get_user_data)):
    return {'user': data[0], 'email': data[1]}
```

To use a `dict` instead, apply the following changes to the example above:

```py
# ...

async def get_user_data():
    user = User(name='john', age=33)
    email = 'user@domain.com'
    return {'user': user, 'email': email}


@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(data: dict = Depends(get_user_data)):
    return {'user': data['user'], 'email': data['email']}
```

### Option 1 - Return an object of a custom Python class

Another way to approach this issue would be to create a custom Python class with the relevant data, instantiate the class inside the dependency function to create an object, and finally, return the object to the endppoint. For simplicity, one could use Python's [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)—as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804)— where special methods, such as such as `__init__()` and `__repr__()` can be automatically added.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from dataclasses import dataclass

app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    

@dataclass
class UserData:
    user: User
    email: str

    
async def get_user_data():
    user = User(name='john', age=33)
    email = 'user@domain.com'
    return UserData(user, email)


@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(data: UserData = Depends(get_user_data)):
    return {'user': data.user, 'email': data.email}
```

### Option 3 - Use `request.state` to store arbitrary data

A further, and maybe simpler, way to store such arbitrary data would be to use `request.state`, which would allow you to retrieve these data later in the endpoint, using the `Request` object. For more details and examples on this approach (as well as on global `dependencies` and `request.state` in FastAPI), I would highly suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    
    
async def get_current_user(request: Request):
    user = User(name='john', age=33)
    request.state.email = 'user@domain.com'
    return user

@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(request: Request, user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return {'user': user, 'email': request.state.email}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris.  Does it matter if I use the request.state as an endpoint, or can it be used within another function?

If I set the:  request.state.email = db.query(User).filter(User.email == email).first().   Can I access this from s3.create_upload_files?  Thank you.

Comment: As long as the `request` object is available in that endpoint/function/dependency, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies, i.e. `Depends` or `Annotated` parameters, are only injected in routes by FastAPI.

If your `s3_create_upload_files()` function is called from your route function, you should declare all dependencies as your route parameters and pass them when you call `s3_create_upload_file()`. Here is an example:

```py
@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(
    file: UploadFile,
    current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user), 
    db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
    do_whatever()
    s3_create_upload_files(file, current_user, db)
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```