# Using FastAPI dependencies/security and inject current user on function handler

Tags: fastapi

I would like to setup a Bearer Token in path operation like below:

```
app.include_router(
    users_router,
    tags=["Users"],
    prefix="",
    dependencies=[Depends(auth.get_current_active_user)],
)
```

It is working. The problem is that I would like to fetch the current user inside the handler function.

I could do this with each function, but it would be time consuming and error prone.

```
@users_router.get("/me")
async def read_users_me(current_user: str = Security(get_current_active_user)):
    return current_user
```

Is there way to declare dependecy in router, and have the current user injected into the function?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804)