# How can I pass data from API endpoint (request) to middleware in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, middleware, starlette, fastapi-middleware

I would like to implement a logic where every API endpoint will have its API Credits (`int`), which I am going to use in an HTTP middleware to deduct credits from the user's balance.

I have searched a lot but have been unable to find any solution. Could anyone help me to achieve this? I am providing a pseudo-code to explain what I am trying to achieve.

```py
@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):

    # here I want to read API credits for request
    print(request.api_credit)

    response = await call_next(request)
    return response

    
@app.post("/myendpoint1")
async def myendpoint1():
    
    # define api credit for this endpoint
    api_credit = 2
    
    return {"message": "myendpoint"}


@app.post("/myendpoint2")
async def myendpoint2():
    
    # define api credit for this endpoint
    api_credit = 5
    
    return {"message": "myendpoint2"}
```

Comment: `request.state` can be used to pass a value between middlewares and the request endpoints, so maybe `request.state.api_credit_cost = None` at the beginning, and then you assign a value to that key inside your endpoint? Another option is to always return the api cost as part of the response and then read it out, or create a custom response that wraps another response type, which contains the api cost as an additional property (`APICostResponse(JSONResponse(...), cost=5)`.

Answer (score 1):

As demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804), one could use `request.state` to store arbitrary state and pass data between middlewares and FastAPI endpoints. Please refer to those answers for more details.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request


app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def some_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    # initialize `api_credits` variable to None
    request.state.api_credits = None
    
    # process the request
    response = await call_next(request)
    
    # read API credits for this request
    print(request.state.api_credits)
    
    return response


@app.get("/")
async def main(request: Request):
    # set api credits for this request
    request.state.api_credits = 5
    return {"message": "ok"}
```