# Pass a dependency value to another dependency in fastapi

Tags: python-3.x, dependency-injection, fastapi

I have a generator function:

```
def get_db() -> Generator[Session, None, None]:
    session = Session(engine, expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=False)
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        session.close()
```

I use it in fastapi code, like so:

```
@router.post("/{roleplay_id}/begin")
async def begin_roleplay_session(
    roleplay_id: int,
    request: Request,
    session=Depends(get_db),
    user=Depends(authenticate_user),
    user_mapping_validation=Depends(validate_roleplay_to_user_mapping),
):
```

I want the `get_db` function to evolve so that I can pass the `autocommit` flag from the caller.. Also, I want to ensure validate_roleplay_to_user_mapping gets `session` as parameter the session object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Implementation will depend on how do you want to pass that `autocommit` flag (`Query` parameters, `Body` or something else). But in any case you need to add a parameter to your `get_db` function. For Query parameters it will be just `def get_db(autocommit: bool) -> Generator[Session, None, None]:`

Comment: If you want to pass this parameter not from API-client, but from endpoint function that uses this dependency, you can just create 2 different get_db dependencies (`get_db` and `get_db_autocommit`). Or you can use parametrized dependencies (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/advanced-dependencies/)

Comment: How do I pass session to `validate_roleplay_to_user_mapping`?

Comment: @YuriiMotov I am ok with 2 dependencies one for `get_db` another for `get_db_autocommit`. However the problem to pass the session to `validate_roleplay_to_user_mapping` dependency is still there. Can that be done?

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77790972/17865804)

Comment: Why don't you just add `session=Depends(get_db)` to the parameters of `validate_roleplay_to_user_mapping`?

Comment: Why wouldn't that create another instance of "session" @YuriiMotov?

Comment: FastAPI caches dependencies for every API call. So, if you add `session=Depends(get_db)` to `begin_roleplay_session` and to `validate_roleplay_to_user_mapping`, than it will be the same session. Docs: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/sub-dependencies/#using-the-same-dependency-multiple-times

Comment: That helps! BTW - can I use Depends in background tasks OR even usually in line inside my code? Would it work the same way?