# How to execute after dependency when using the add_middleware method in FastAPI?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi, middleware

In my project, I need to protect some API Endpoints. To do this, I have defined an auth check function that checks the authentication and authorization of a particular user.

I then include this as a dependency to all my API routes that need protection like so:

```
app.include_router(
admin_router,
tags=["admin"],
prefix="/admin",
dependencies=[Depends(auth_check)],)
```

I now want to track usage stats, and have defined a middleware function with background tasks like so:

```py
async def record_api_usage_to_db_middleware(request: Request, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, call_next, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    response = await call_next(request)
    background_tasks.add_task(record_api_usage_to_db, db, request)
    return response
```

The above code sits in a separate file called middlewares.py. I then add this to my main.py file where we instantiate the FastAPI object like so:

```
from middlewares import record_api_usage_to_db
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends, status
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware, dispatch= record_api_usage_to_db_middleware)
```

I want this middleware to run only for authenticated endpoints and AFTER the auth has happened since I need some metadata from the authentication/authorization step to be included in the usage data.

I am not sure how to do this, because it seems FastAPI does not allow dependencies in middleware. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Could you have `auth_check` ask for the request (`request: Request`) and then set `request.state` inside the dependency to "mark" it as being authenticated? It's a dependency that gets hidden, and I'm not too fond of having "magic" keys that needs to be populated somewhere out of sight, but it should work for what you need as far as I can tell - you then check `request.state` after you've gotten the response back from `call_next`.

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, that's what I am doing, but how do I ensure this happens before the middleware is called? I cannot make my auth a middleware since the library used for auth needs to use the dependency injection system. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry; I misunderstood - I thought you explicitly wanted to run it after the request had finished. In that case - you have the parsed request in `request` - could you just call `auth_check` manually?

Comment: @MatsLindh If I called it manually,, instead of passing it as a dependency, the downstream dependency injections will get invalidated I believe. On top of that, I think our auth provider integration requires us to use the auth as a dependency.

Comment: You could either use `request.state`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77790972/17865804) (and its references), in order to store some kind of state when in the endpoint that would help you to check, afterwards, in the middleware whether or not the user has passed authentication, or check the response status code, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77626671/17865804), for the same purpose as mentioned earlier.

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful as well: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75729917/17865804)

Comment: @Chris thanks. It seems that the dependency is run first given my syntax. As such, when I add the following to my middleware, it works as expected. Appreciate the references - this was what I ended up using:
tasks = BackgroundTasks()
tasks.add_task(record_api_usage_to_db, request)
response.background = tasks